# only one circle on iphone simulator!

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

How can i get only one finger(circle) on iphone simulator!?

Is there any other way than moving two circles closer!(overlapping two circles)?

Im able to get two circles by holding opt button! but i want only one circle..

thanks in adv.,

Comment: @BoltClock He wants the effect that you see with the option key, but he only wants it to happen with one circle - most likely for a screencast.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [product called SimFinger](http://blog.atebits.com/2009/03/not-your-average-iphone-screencast/) that will get a circle for you. I am assuming that you are trying to make a screencast. The blog I linked to has some other tips about tweaks to make screencasts on the simulator.